# Creating a directions app where users can refine their search by deleting highways and named roads of their choice

Tags: maps

I would like to create an app where users can get directions but they can select to avoid highways and/or roads/highways with a certain name . On google maps you can easily tell the difference between highways(orange), main routes(yellow), and roads(white) so google must be able to differentiate between them. Also the roads and highways are all named in google maps. I would like to give the user the ability to refine their directions search by deleting highways, routes, rural roads, and/or named roads if they so choose. Can someone point me in the right direction (no pun intended) on making this idea feasible? Also does the google  maps api allow us access to tweaking how directions are calculated?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question (a general request for guidance) is a tad too general for StackOverflow- it should be about a specific, answerable programming problem, ideally including some code.

Comment: This is an aside, but maybe you don't need to make such an app, since Google has some ways of specifying which places to avoid: http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24867

Answer (score 0):

The API will let you avoid highways or tolls, but not specifically named routes.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests